# React Native - How to build app with specific simulator and iOS version

Tags: ios, react-native, command-line, build, ios-simulator

I have diffrend simulators with differed iOS version. How can I build app with the one I want specifically?

Answer (score 0):

First get a list of simulators by this command:

```
xcrun simctl list devices
```

the result will be something like this:

```
iPhone 8 (1A6DE54B-9DBF-4AF7-AB1E-DD577C89F7C7) (Shutdown) 
iPhone 8 Plus (21E1A66C-2122-47D8-BC28-99D67ED04BDB) (Shutdown) 
iPhone 11 (28DFD4DF-9E36-41AB-BB83-332FDAFDB1DE) (Shutdown)
```

then use this command with the code of the simulator you chose:

```
npx react-native run-ios --udid [CODE]
```